# Javascript add text to div by classname not adding and no errors either

Tags: javascript

I have a div with a class name:

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

And now I want to add some text to it, so I used this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").innerHTML = 'Testing here';
```

For some reason no text is added and also console is not giving me any errors either.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns array-like object, you have to use index.

I will also suggest you to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
 instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with text only content.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].textContent = 'Testing here';
```

```html
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Comment: is see people already answered it, but when something isnt working you should console log it to see what is the issue. That will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")` will return collection. So either you need to loop through each element or just use indexing if there is only one element

`document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].innerHTML = 'Testing here';`

```js
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
      elements[i].innerHTML = 'Testing here';
    }
```

```html
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector` also. Here's an example usage

```html
    <div class="myclass"></div>
```

```js
    document.querySelector(".myclass").textContent = 'Testing here';
```

Using `querySelector` returns a single element with specified css selector